# How to find a variable and replace it with other variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have tried the below Perl command to find a `$from_word` variable and replace it with `$to_word` variable in the `$bat_file_path` file.

```
system("perl -i -p -e 's/$from_word/$to_word/ee' $bat_file_path");
```

but I get error as

```
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 4.
```

Also it did not replaced as expected.

Please help me out of this concern.

```
sub change_cg_name {
  if(!-e $output_running) {
    print ("show running file not available. test case failed. [$output_running]");
    return 0;
  }
  if(!-e $bat_file_path) {
    print ("bat file not available test case filed. [$bat_file_path]");
    return 0
  }
  my $from_word=`grep 'config-group type node IMPT_' $bat_file_path  | awk '{print \$(4)}'`;
  my $to_word=  `grep 'config-group type node IMPT_' $output_running | awk '{print \$(4)}'`;
  print("from WORD IS [$from_word]");
  print("TO WORD IS [$to_word]");
  if($to_word ne "") {
    if (index($to_word, "IMPT_") != -1) {
      system("perl -i -p -e 's/"$from_word"/"$to_word"/ee' $bat_file_path");
      system("perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n$/\n/g' $bat_file_path");
      print("ARUL changed the impt name in the bat file [$to_word] and file [$bat_file_path]");
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do $from_word or $to_word contain any special characters (`/` etc.)?

Comment: It contains Under score (_).

Comment: This is working for me. Can you show what have you assign to $from_word and $to_word?

Comment: Be aware that the `$from_word` and `$to_word` values both end with a newline. Read about `chomp`

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
system("perl -i -p -e 's/"$from_word"/"$to_word"/ee' $bat_file_path");
```

with

```
system("perl -i -p -e 's/$from_word/$to_word/ee' $bat_file_path");
```

Comment: syntax error at ./sc_auto.pl line 252, near "'perl -i -p -e 's/"$from_word"/"$to_word"/ee"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at ./sc_auto.pl line 265.

Comment: You didn't replace the line, still you have same line.

Comment: This `"'perl -i -p -e 's/"$from_word"/"$to_word"/ee"` should be `"perl -i -p -e 's/$from_word/$to_word/ee' path\to\file"`, this will not give syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

1. serenesat is right in removing the incorrectly nested quotation marks.
2. glenn jackman is right in pointing to the line endings in the `$from_word` and `$to_word` values. Instead of removing them, I suggest not to produce them in the first place by changing the awk command `print \$(4)` to `printf "%s", \$(4)`.
3. Finally, in the command `system("perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n$/\n/g' $bat_file_path")` the `\n` and `$` need \-escaping: `system("perl -p -i -e 's/\r\\n\$/\\n/g' $bat_file_path")`.